# How do I level up my wizard to level 2?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, character-advancement, character-levels

How do I level up my wizard to level 2?

I need answer by today, so please hurry up and come up with an answer cause I am running out of time.

Comment: Do you have any of the rule books?

Comment: Also, what are you actually asking about? Are you asking how you gain levels such as the current answer provides the rules for or are you asking what features you gain when you level up? I’m voting to put this on hold as unclear until clarified.

Comment: Hi creeperfighter8! Welcome to [RPG Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com). Please, take our [tour], it only takes a minute, I promise! Then, if you have some time, read our [help] to understand more about how this community works. Your question seems **very basic** -without offend-, have you actually read the [Basic D&D 5e Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) or google it?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey he said "How do I level up" not "What I get on level up". The question is perfectly clear, though very basic and without any previous effort (at least, he could have google it before [first two links](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+level+up+in+D%26D+5e&oq=how+do+I+level+up+in+D%26D+5e&aqs=chrome..69i57.6679j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). But in the case he is asking the second question [from RPG SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108952/can-anybody-give-me-a-simple-guide-to-leveling-up-a-character).

Comment: Please review [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108952/22566) and [the basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf).  Once you have done so, please come back and clarify the question so that what you don't understand is more clear.  Do you have the Players Handbook?  If you don't, knowing that will be helpful to people trying to answer your question .

Answer (score 10):

Seriously talking (without trying to offend), you should read the *Player's Handbook.* If you can't afford it, you can read the [Official and Free Basic Rules PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf).

From page 16 of the *Player's Handbook* or page 12 of the Basic Rules:

> As your character goes on adventures and overcomes challenges, he or she gains experience, represented by experience points. A character who reaches a specified experience point total advances in capability. This advancement is called **gaining a level.**

<sup>Emphasis not mine</sup>

Your class (Wizard) doesn't matter when we are talking about levelling up.

> The Character Advancement table summarizes the XP you need to advance in levels from level 1 through level 20, and the proficiency bonus for a character of that level. Consult the information in your character's c1ass description to see what other improvements you gain at each level.

## Character Advancement

$$ \left|
    \begin{array}{cc|cc}
\text{Experience Points}&\text{Level}&\text{Experience Points}&\text{Level}\\
0&1&85,000&11\\
300&2&100,000&12\\
900&3&120,000&13\\
2,700&4&140,000&14\\
6,500&5&165,000&15\\
14,000&6&195,000&16\\
23,000&7&225,000&17\\
34,000&8&265,000&18\\
48,000&9&305,000&19\\
64,000&10&355,000&20\\
    \end{array}
\right| $$

So, in order to reach level 2, you must have earned a total amount of 300 experience points.

#### Level 3

Additionally, I will explain to you how to reach 3rd level as a gift. Once you reach 2nd level, you don't need to earn 900 experience points. You need to earn only 600.

Why?

The table shows how much total experience you need to reach a certain level. When you level up, you **don't lose your current experience points**, they get stored. That is why you only need 600 experience as shown in the following calculation:

$$ \text{XP for next level} - \text{Current XP} = \text{XP you must earn} $$
$$ 900 - 300 = 600 \text{ XP}$$

#### Level 20

Also, when you reach level 20, you **stop levelling up**. Instead, you start getting something called Epic Boons, but since you are just level 1, you don't need to know what they are yet.

## Experience Points

I'm not exactly sure where it's written in those two books mentioned above, but in page 260 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*:

> Experience points (XP) fuel level advancement for player characters and are most often the reward for completing combat encounters. **Each monster has an XP value based on its challenge rating. When adventurers defeat one or more
> monsters-typically by killing, routing, or capturing them-they divide the total XP value of the monsters evenly among themselves.** If the party received substantial assistance from one or more NPCs, count those NPCs as party members when dividing up the XP. [...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Basically, the easiest way to "gather" or earn experience points is by killing stuff (usually monsters), crawling in dungeons, completing missions or quests and performing adventures. Although, violence isn't the only way to archive new levels, avoiding combat, capturing enemies or negotiating are also other sources of experience points. For example, a very politics-based story may reward characters with experience points if they succeed in their political... stuff, like commerce, dethroning a king or a political figure, etc.

Remember, you Dungeons Masters (also known as Game Masters) can make new ways to get experience points. For example, some DMs allow characters to convert money to experience points.